# how to use of cordova sqlite plugin in android studio

Tags: sqlite, cordova, android-studio

I develop a Cordova project that use Sqlite plugin ,  It works as expected

But for some reasons i import that in android studio with follow this article

> http://www.catharinegeek.com/embed-cordova-webview-in-android-native-app/

you can see project structure in below for details

[project structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqMdl.png)

when i run project i got this error

```
"java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load sqlc-native-driver from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.cyan.amir.calendarplusevent-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.cyan.amir.calendarplusevent-1, /system/lib, /system/lib/arm, /data/downloads]]]: findLibrary returned null"

at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
at io.liteglue.SQLiteConnector.<init>(SQLiteConnector.java:8)
at io.sqlc.SQLiteConnectorDatabase.<clinit>(SQLiteConnectorDatabase.java:36)
at io.sqlc.SQLitePlugin.openDatabase(SQLitePlugin.java:227)
at io.sqlc.SQLitePlugin.access$000(SQLitePlugin.java:35)
at io.sqlc.SQLitePlugin$DBRunner.run(SQLitePlugin.java:398)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I dubug that and i found code break in this line :

```
this.cordova.getThreadPool().execute(r);
```

of SQLitePlugin.java file

I test Cordova project with visual studio 2015 and that works correctly

how can i use sqlite plugin added to cordova in android studio?